# Angular JS and Store DB like persistance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-webkit

I've got an AngularJS app with a movies array in my controllers.

```
    app.controller("MoviesListCtrl", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
        $scope.movies = [
            {
                id:1,
                originalTitle:'Gone with the Wind',
                year: 2008
            },
            {
                id:2,
                originalTitle:'Back To The Future',
                year: 1988
            }
        ];

        $scope.addMovie = function(){
            $scope.movies.push({
                id:3,
                originalTitle: 'Mitchell and Jackie'
            })
        };
    }
]);
```

I'd like to simply store these objects on a database, and be able to find them by their properties. I'm using node-webkit, and about data storage, the developer gives the example of StoreDB (https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app - https://github.com/djyde/StoreDB/blob/master/README_EN.md).

I find StoreDB really simple, and it seems to fit my needs. But how can I bind it with Angular ? Have you got an equivalent made for Angular ?

Thank you